# Binding ViewModel property in DataTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I have a Prop1 and a Prop2 property in a ViewModel (XYViewModel.cs) and this XAML (XY.xaml):

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Prop1}">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <...Source="{Binding Prop2}"...>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
</GridView>
```

How could I reach Prop2 property in the Grid? I need to use it in another binding.

Thx for the help

Answer (score 1):

```
<SomeElement SomeProperty="{Binding DataContext.Prop2, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=GridView}}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Binding with parent element in XAML.
For example

```
<Grid x:Name="ParentGrid">

    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Prop1}">
        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <...Source="{Binding DataContext.Prop2, ElementName=ParentGrid}"...>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I don't think this will work. `ElementName` bindings have a limited scope (the [NameScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746659.aspx) actually). The `ParentGrid` is clearly outside the NameScope of the `DataTemplate`.